# Filters using equiripple approximations (different from type I lowpass)

Tags: filter-design, finite-impulse-response, linear-phase, parks-mclellan

In Oppenheim & Schafer's *Discrete-Time Signal Processing*, only type I lowpass filters are explained in detail in the chapter *"Optimum Approximations of FIR filters"*.

I want to know what happens not only with the other three types of generalized-phase filters, but also understand how the equiripple approximation works with bandpass and highpass filters.

In the previously mentioned book, it says:

> Specifically, we will show that for **type I lowpass** filters:
>
> - The maximum possible number of alternations of the error is $L+3$.
> - Alternations will always occur at $\omega_p$ and $\omega_s$.
> - [...] the filter will be equiripple, except possibly at $\omega=0$ and $\omega =\pi$.

I have a bunch of questions, for example:

- Is there a maximum possible number of alternations for every type (II, III, IV) and kind (lowpass, highpass, bandpass) of filter?
- Do the other two properties (alternations at edges and equiripple-ness except possibly at $0$ and $\pi$) apply to other types and kinds of filters?
- Do other types and kinds of filters have other special properties (i.e., properties that differ from the ones in the quote I wrote)?

It would be great if you could give me some insight in the subject, or if you could recommend a book to which I could fall back on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place where I found the answer to this question was in *Theory and Application of Digital Signal Processing* by Rabiner & Gold.

In its chapter about theory and approximation of FIR filters, there is a section where all of my questions are explicitely answered:

[image]